# Derivative of the error for Lagrange interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-interpolation

I was reading a book and I have found this. If $f(x)=L(x)+R(x)$, with $L$ the quadratic interpolation with three points $x_0, x_1$ and $x_2$, It has been said that it must be true that $$R(x)=\dfrac{f'''(\epsilon(x))}{6} (x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2),$$ for some $x_0<\epsilon(x)<x_2$, and $$R'(x)=\dfrac{f^{(4)}(\mu)}{24} (x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+\dfrac{f'''(\epsilon(x))}{6}D((x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2))$$  where D is the derivative operator and $\mu$ was not described.

How can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Another form for the remainder](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3386554/115115) is $R(x)=f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x](x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ so as difference quotient you get
\begin{align}
\frac{R(x+h)-R(x)}{h}&=\frac{f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x+h]\prod_{j=0}^2(x+h-x_j)-f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x]\prod_{j=0}^2(x-x_j)}{h}
\\
&=f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x]\frac{\prod_{j=0}^2(x+h-x_j)-\prod_{j=0}^2(x-x_j)}h
\\&\qquad+f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x,x+h]\prod_{j=0}^2(x+h-x_j)
\end{align}
By the theorems of divided differences of higher order, your claim directly follows,
$$
f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x]=\frac1{3!}f'''(ϵ(x))~\text{ and }~f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x,x+h]=\frac1{4!}f^{(4)}(μ(x))
$$
with $ϵ(x)$ and $μ(x)$ some points contained in the convex hull of/the interval spanned by the points $x_0,x_1,x_2,x,x+h$.

Comment: Man, you are blassed. A lot of similar questions appear in my reseach! You need know that you are doing math better!