# Error term in polynomial interpolation of non-differentiable function

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error) it is said that the error when interpolating a function $f(t)$ at $n+1$ distinct points $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$ using a polynomial $P_n(t)$ of degree $n$, the error term is given by:

$$f(t) - P_n(t) = f[x_0, ..., x_n, t] \prod_{i=0}^{n} (t-x_i)$$

How would I go about proving this statement ? So far, the only thing I've figured out is that at $x_i$, the error is $0$, which satisfies what it means for a polynomial to interpolate a function at $x_i$.

Comment: Start by proving it for $n=0$. Next for $n=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Newton interpolation of degree $n+1$ of $f$ at the points $x_0,...,x_n,t$, 
\begin{align}
P_{n+1}(x)&=f[x_0]+f[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)+f[x_0,x_1,x_2](x-x_0)(x-x_1)+...
\\&\qquad...+f[x_0,...,x_n](x-x_0)...(x-x_{n-1})+f[x_0,...,x_n,t](x-x_0)...(x-x_{n-1})(x-x_n)
\\
&=P_n(x)+f[x_0,...,x_n,t](x-x_0)...(x-x_n).
\end{align}
By construction, this is exact at $x=t$, resulting in
$$
f(t)=P_{n+1}(t)=P_n(t)+f[x_0,...,x_n,t](t-x_0)...(t-x_n),
$$
which is the claimed formula. Non of this uses derivatives, only the function values of $f$.

Of course, in a possible next step connecting the divided differences to derivatives, one would require differentiability of $f$ of a sufficiently high order.